# Can continuous form of tense be used with "for" and "since"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-choice, for

I want to know if it is grammatically correct to use continuous form of tense be used with "for" and "since"?

For example: instead of `They had been friends for six months` if I say `They were friends for six months` then would it be correct.

Also, if you would outline the rules that with which all forms of verb "for" and "since" can be used then it would be very helpful.

Comment: That's not a continuous tense, but it can be used, depending on the context (i.e., *they'd been friends for 6 months* and *they were friends for 6 months* can mean different things).

Comment: If you say *they had been friends for six months* you need to complete the thought. When *what* happened? But, that aside, there is nothing wrong with either form. (Although, as per the other comment, neither is continuous.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Understood. Thanks.